# Script for searching through photos app on Mac:Syntax error

Tags: macos, scripting, applescript

Pretty easy to understand i'm trying to pull all of my videos from the photos app that are over 15 minutes long. Using AppleScripts. please help

```
set minimumDuration to 15 * 60 -- 15 minutes in seconds

tell application "Photos"
    activate
    set libraryFolder to (path to pictures folder as text) & "Photos Library.photoslibrary"
    set mediaItems to every media item whose media type is video
    set longVideos to {}
    repeat with item in mediaItems
        set durationSeconds to duration of item
        if durationSeconds > minimumDuration then
            set end of longVideos to item
        end if
    end repeat
    if (count longVideos) > 0 then
        set selection to longVideos
    else
        display alert "No videos longer than 15 minutes found."
    end if
end tell
```

i am new to the Applescript

Comment: A `media item` has neither a `media type` or `duration` property.  Also note that `item` is an element of a list.

Comment: I'm stuck then I'm looking at the dictionary for photos and I don't see a way to point to the videos portion

Comment: Photos isn’t really the tool to use. The `find` shell utility can be used to find paths for .mov files in the Photos Library, but you would also need to use something like ExifTool to get the duration from the file EXIF metadata.

Comment: `repeat with item in mediaItems` is invalid because `item` is a special identifier. Try changing it to `repeat with element in mediaItems` or something else that isn't reserved.